# Plotly Express Choropleth of Census Data Fails

Tags: python, plotly-python, choropleth

I am attempting to use [Plotly Express](https://plotly.com/python/plotly-express/) to create interactive choropleths of Census data which I retrieve using the [censusdis](https://github.com/censusdis/censusdis) package. This works for two of the variables which I am retrieving, but not the third. Here is my code which demonstrates the issue:

```
import plotly.express as px
import censusdis.data as ced
from censusdis.datasets import ACS5

#variable = 'B19013_001E' # Works - Median Household Income
#variable = 'B25058_001E' # Works - Median Rent
variable = 'B01001_001E' # Does not work! Total Population

df = ced.download(
    dataset=ACS5,
    vintage=2022,         
    download_variables=['NAME', variable], 
    state='06',
    county='075',
    tract='*',
    with_geometry=True)

df = df.set_index('NAME')

print(df.head())

fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(df, 
                           geojson=df.geometry,
                           locations=df.index, 
                           center={'lat': 37.74180915, 'lon': -122.38474831884692}, 
                           color=variable, 
                           color_continuous_scale="Viridis", 
                           mapbox_style="carto-positron", 
                           opacity=0.5,
                           zoom=10)
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
```

As I cycle through the variables, the resulting dataframes all appear similar, but the third one (`B01001_001E`) generates a scale but not a map:[image]

However, the geometry column looks fine (and, in fact, looks like the same as that returned for the other variables). I would appreciate any help understanding what the problem is and advice on how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the return value from `ced.download` there are some missing values. You can see them with

```py
print(df[df.isna().any(axis='columns')])
```

which produces

```
                                                   STATE COUNTY   TRACT  B01001_001E geometry
NAME                                                                                         
Census Tract 9901; San Francisco County; Califo...    06    075  990100            0     None
Census Tract 9902; San Francisco County; Califo...    06    075  990200            0     None
```

If you get rid of those with

```py
df = df.dropna()
```

then it works fine.

Comment: Also, minor style comment: you may have looked up the county FIPS code `'075'` on a site like https://www.cccarto.com/fipscodes/california/. Instead, you could have used `from censusdis.counties.california import SAN_FRANCISCO` to get it symbolicly. And similarly, `from censusdis.states import CA` instead of `'06'`.